# JavaScript Animations pause when scrolling on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, jquery-animate

So I have some animations on a page, I'm using jQuery to do that. Now, when I browse my web page on an iPad and I'm scrolling the page, all animations pause.

**What kind of animations ?** Well, like a *Carousel*, a *Scrollable* area, those kind of things.

Also I have a header to whom I apply `position:fixed` when the scroll is greater than `300px`. To do that I'm using a `setInterval` on `if(offset>300)` that repeats itself each **250 ms**.

So when I scroll the page, all animations pause, until I leave the screen.

I guess that that must be a common behavior, I'm hoping that there will be a solution for it.

Comment: AFAIK thats because the browser stops all js while you scroll, so.. no solution. however, im not really sure about this.

Comment: do you mean stop, or _pause_ (i.e. do they start up again when you've finished scrolling) ?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes I meant pause. The animations start again the scroll has finished

Comment: @Jarry I thought the same, good question though, be interesting to see if there were any workarounds.

Comment: @Jarry That's correct - in iOS animation pauses while the user is scrolling. You can test with the code I put up here: http://jsfiddle.net/efDNw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jarry Said : "AFAIK thats because the browser stops all js while you scroll, so.. no solution. however, im not really sure about this"